# C++: не хватает точности вычислений?

Tags: c++, математика, double, погрешность, точность

**У меня стояла следующая задача:**

Есть точки, полученные с эксперимента, они описываются некоторой теоретической гладкой функцией *f(x)*, которая описывается несколькими параметрами *f(x, p1, p2, ..., pn)*

Стоит задача подобрать параметры *p*, так, чтобы теоретическая функция наиболее точно описывала экспериментальные данные (использовать метод наименьших квадратов) - другими словами чтобы сумма квадрата разницы между теоретическими и экспериментальными значениями была минимальной

```
sum((f(x) - data(x))^2) -> min
```

**Решение**

Поскольку теоретическая функция очень сложная (сумма двух логнормальных распределений, 5(6) параметров)

```
const long double f1 = a1 * exp(-(log(x) - mu1) * (log(x) - mu1) / (2.0 * sigma1 * sigma1)) / (x * sigma1 * 2.506628274631000502415765284811);

const long double f2 = a2 * exp(-(log(x) - mu2) * (log(x) - mu2) / (2.0 * sigma2 * sigma2)) / (x * sigma2 * 2.506628274631000502415765284811);

const long double f = f1 + f2
```

То к дополнительному перебору параметров от 'min' до 'max' я добавил оптимизации, позволяющие существенно ускорить код.

Например, поскольку функция гладкая, то изменяя параметр можно добиться того, что теоретическая функция сначала будет все ближе и ближе подходить к экспериментальной, а потом начнёт отходить и в этот момент в принципе можно прекращать наращивать параметр и переходить к следующем.

**Проблема**

Все было бы замечательно, но решив посмотреть описанное выше поведение увидел следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. вначале плавное снижение (приближение к теоретическому), а потом какая-то фигня.

```
0,13186800  0,000119252701172278
0,13189500  0,000119239008348983
0,13192200  0,000119242281293030
0,13194900  0,000119245605642282
0,13197600  0,000119248981396740
0,13200300  0,000119252408556403
0,13203000  0,000119255887121271
0,13205700  0,000119241658719692
0,13208400  0,000119245240094971
0,13211100  0,000119248872875455
0,13213800  0,000119252557061144
0,13216500  0,000119256292652038
0,13219200  0,000119241551855830
0,13221900  0,000119245390257135
```

Подскажите с чем это может быть связано и как с этим бороться?
Мне кажется, что точности рассчётов уже не хватает просто, хотя используется 'long double'

**P.S.**

А вот как выглядят графики приближения - видно, что довольно точно все подходит, но чего-то не хватает, может как раз из-за описанной проблемы и не удается наложить графики более точно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.P.S.**

Ну или предположение о гладком поведении при изменении одного параметра является ошибочным :( но вроде нет

**P.P.P.S.**

Кто хочет посмотреть код:

Исходник + файл, содержащий данные

https://yadi.sk/i/wtYtXss83YrUJc исходник (cpp)

https://yadi.sk/d/dvEnweGL3YrUFR данные

```
// ols.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <conio.h>

std::vector<std::string> splitString(_In_ const std::string& strData, _In_ const std::string& strSubString)
{
    std::vector<std::string> lResult;
    size_t szOffset = std::string::npos;
    std::string strCurrentSlice = strData;

    while ((szOffset = strCurrentSlice.find(strSubString)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        lResult.push_back(strCurrentSlice.substr(0, szOffset));
        strCurrentSlice = strCurrentSlice.substr(szOffset + strSubString.length());
    }

    lResult.push_back(strCurrentSlice);

    return lResult;
}

int main()
{
    struct point_t
    {
        long double x;
        long double x_ln;
        long double y;
    };

    // считать файл
    std::ifstream data(L"d:\\science\\data.dat");

    std::string line;

    point_t* pointsData = new point_t[10000];

    int pointsAmount = 0;

    while (std::getline(data, line))
    {
        // распарсить строку
        std::vector<std::string> parts = splitString(line, ";");

        pointsData[pointsAmount].x      = (long double)stod(parts[0]);
        pointsData[pointsAmount].x_ln   = (pointsData[pointsAmount].x == 0.0) ? 0 : log(pointsData[pointsAmount].x);
        pointsData[pointsAmount].y      = (long double)stod(parts[1]);

        pointsAmount++;
    }

    data.close();

    // подобрать коэффициенты
    struct CParameter
    {
        typedef std::pair<long double, long double> start_point_pr;

        long double min;
        long double max;
        long double delta;
        int         steps_amount;

        CParameter(const long double in_min, const long double in_max, const int in_steps_amount)
        {
            min = in_min;
            max = in_max;
            steps_amount = in_steps_amount;

            delta = (max - min) / steps_amount;
        }

        CParameter(const start_point_pr& in_ave, const int in_steps_amount)
        {
            min = in_ave.first * (1.0 - in_ave.second);
            max = in_ave.first * (1.0 + in_ave.second);
            steps_amount = in_steps_amount;

            delta = (max - min) / steps_amount;
        }

        CParameter(const long double in_ave, const int in_steps_amount)
            : CParameter(start_point_pr(in_ave, 0.3), in_steps_amount)
        {}

        void compact(const long double current)
        {
            min = current - delta * 2.5;
            max = current + delta * 2.5;

            delta = (max - min) / steps_amount;
        }
    };

    int         approximationMax = 5;

    const int   xIndexMin = 1;
    const int   xIndexMax = 200;// pointsAmount;

    CParameter  _sigma1(0.61991875, 50);
    CParameter  _mu1(3.72709594, 50);
    CParameter  _a1(0.86259259, 15);

    CParameter  _sigma2(0.09229050, 50);
    CParameter  _mu2(4.54333653, 50);
    CParameter  _a2(0.13740741, 15);

    long double olsSigma1 = 0.0;
    long double olsMu1 = 0.0;
    long double olsA1 = 0.0;

    long double olsSigma2 = 0.0;
    long double olsMu2 = 0.0;
    long double olsA2 = 0.0;

    __int64 maxCounter = (__int64)_sigma1.steps_amount * (__int64)_mu1.steps_amount * (__int64)_a1.steps_amount * 
                         (__int64)_sigma2.steps_amount * (__int64)_mu2.steps_amount /** (__int64)_a2.steps_amount*/ *
                         (__int64)approximationMax;
    __int64 localCounter = 0;

    long double olsMinCoeff = 1e20;

    for (int approximationIndex = 0; approximationIndex < approximationMax; approximationIndex++)
    {
        // перебрать параметры
        for (long double sigma1 = _sigma1.min; sigma1 <= _sigma1.max; sigma1 += _sigma1.delta)
        {
            const long double s1_1 = -1.0 / (2.0 * sigma1 * sigma1);
            const long double s1_2 = sigma1 * 2.506628274631000502415765284811;

            for (long double mu1 = _mu1.min; mu1 <= _mu1.max; mu1 += _mu1.delta)
            {
                for (long double a1 = _a1.min; a1 <= _a1.max; a1 += _a1.delta)
                {
                    const long double a2 = 1.0 - a1;

                    for (long double sigma2 = _sigma2.min; sigma2 <= _sigma2.max; sigma2 += _sigma2.delta)
                    {
                        const long double s2_1 = -1.0 / (2.0 * sigma2 * sigma2);
                        const long double s2_2 = sigma2 * 2.506628274631000502415765284811;

                        for (long double mu2 = _mu2.min; mu2 <= _mu2.max; mu2 += _mu2.delta)
                        {
//                            for (long double a2 = _a2.min; a2 <= _a2.max; a2 += _a2.delta)
//                            {
                                // отобразить информацию
                                localCounter++;

                                if ((localCounter % 100000) == 0)
                                {
                                    const long double process = 100.0 * (long double)localCounter / (long double)maxCounter;

                                    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << process << "% (" << approximationIndex << ") | ols: " << std::setprecision(8) << (olsMinCoeff / 1000000.0) <<
                                        " | sigma1: " << olsSigma1 << " mu1: " << olsMu1 << " a1: " << olsA1 <<
                                        " | sigma2: " << olsSigma2 << " mu2: " << olsMu2 << " a2: " << olsA2 << "      \r";
                                }

                                // вычислить МНК коэффициент
                                long double olsCoeff = 0.0;

                                for (int xIndex = xIndexMin; xIndex < xIndexMax; xIndex++)
                                {
                                    const long double x     = pointsData[xIndex].x;
                                    const long double x_ln  = pointsData[xIndex].x_ln;
                                    const long double y     = pointsData[xIndex].y * 1000.0;

//                                    const long double formula1 = a1 * exp(-(x_ln - mu1) * (x_ln - mu1) / (2.0 * sigma1 * sigma1)) / (x * sigma1 * 2.506628274631000502415765284811);
//                                    const long double formula2 = a2 * exp(-(x_ln - mu2) * (x_ln - mu2) / (2.0 * sigma2 * sigma2)) / (x * sigma2 * 2.506628274631000502415765284811);

                                    const long double formula1 = a1 * exp((x_ln - mu1) * (x_ln - mu1) * s1_1) / (x * s1_2);
                                    const long double formula2 = a2 * exp((x_ln - mu2) * (x_ln - mu2) * s2_1) / (x * s2_2);

                                    const long double formula = (formula1 + formula2) * 1000.0;

                                    olsCoeff += (formula - y) * (formula - y);

                                    // если вычисленный МНК коэффициент превысил максимальный МНК коэффициент, прекратить дальнейший анализ точек для заданной совокупности параметров
                                    if (olsCoeff > olsMinCoeff)
                                        break;
                                }

                                // рассчитать коэффициент
                                if (olsCoeff < olsMinCoeff)
                                {
                                    olsMinCoeff = olsCoeff;

                                    olsA1 = a1;
                                    olsMu1 = mu1;
                                    olsSigma1 = sigma1;

                                    olsA2 = a2;
                                    olsMu2 = mu2;
                                    olsSigma2 = sigma2;
                                }
//                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // скорректировать (сузить) диапазон, в котором могут меняться коэффициенты
        _sigma1.compact(olsSigma1);
        _mu1.compact(olsMu1);
        _a1.compact(olsA1);

        _sigma2.compact(olsSigma2);
        _mu2.compact(olsMu2);
        _a2.compact(olsA2);
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << "sigma1: " << olsSigma1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << "mu1: " << olsMu1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << "a1: " << olsA1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << "sigma2: " << olsSigma2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << "mu2: " << olsMu2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << "a2: " << olsA2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << std::endl << "ols: " << olsMinCoeff << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press any key to continue" << std::endl;
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Т.е. вы просто минимизируете целевую функцию от 6 переменных (по две а, мю и сигма) методом покоординатного спуска, так? Что у вас за первый график - это по одной переменной смещение? По какой именно? Все ли ведут себя таким образом? Ощущение (*ничем не обоснованное :)*), что у вас вычислительные погрешности начинают играть роль...

Comment: Именно так, пока по 6 переменным, когда все заработает, то сделаю по 5 (потому что a1 + a2 = 1). Использую "метод покоординатного спуска" (не знал, что так называется), зависимо для каждой из 6 переменных (т.е. у меня вложенные друг в друга 6 циклов `for`). На всех переменных не проверял, проверил на самой глубоковложенной. Очень может быть, что и вычислительная погрешность, хотя думал, что `long double` должен справиться, все таки 10 байт на число.

Comment: Возможно погрешность накапливается из-за того, что для всех точек (у меня - 200) производится операция `total += f(x)`, а поскольку `f(x)` даёт значения порядка e-9, а (y-f(x))^2 порядка у-10, то погрешность и накапливается. Думаете стоит предварительно умножать скажем на миллион-миллиард?

Comment: Скорее вам надо стараться держаться ближе к 1, так как в этом случае точность вычислений будет наилучшей. Суммирование чисел с большим разбросом значений вообще одна из основных причин потерь точности. Для суммирования есть [алгоритм Кахана](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). А вообще стоило бы привести полноценный пример кода, выдающий такие результата.

Comment: Добавлю, что покоординатный спуск проходит координаты неоднократно - по 1 переменной, второй, ..., шестой, опять первой, - и так далее, пока смещения по всем шести будут в пределах устраивающей погрешности. Вариант попробовать все же расписать математику МНК (производные) и решать систему нелинейных уравнений - вообще-то надо смотреть, что будет попроще..

Comment: Увидеть код было-бы лучше , чтоб быстрее разобраться , баги они такие, скрытные. Увидел только что числа в программе double точности, чтобы было long нужно добавлять букву L. 3.1415L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harry подкинул идею, что дело действительно может быть в проседании точности при многократных вычислениях.

Поэтому я при вычислении `f = f1 + f1` произвёл умножение на 1000. В результате получилось следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

График стал гладким и это хорошо!

Но вот имеет несколько минимумов, хотя рассчитывал на монотонно убывающую и возрастающую :(

В связи с этим наверное метод описанный в вопросе работать не будет

**P.S.**

Все, можно сказать что со второй частью вопроса разобрался :(
Конечно нельзя ожидать монотонного поведения функции и я наблюдал такое только потому, что смотрел за одним (линейным) коэффициентом, а для произвольного коэффициента это не так:

Например:

```
f = a1*exp(-(ln(x)-m1)^2/(2s1^2))/(x*s1) + a2*exp(-(ln(x)-m2)^2/(2s2^2))/(x*s2)
```

при свободном коэффициента `a1` может рассматриваться как

`f(a1) = a1 * c1 + c2` (где c1 и c2 - константы) и тут всё просто

при свободном коэффициенте 's1' все заметно сложнее (считаем производную)

**P.P.S.**

Пришла в голову такая оптимизация - поскольку график все таки гладкий, можно опираться на его поведение и пропускать некоторые точки для анализа, например: если коэффициент начал расти, не рассматривать следующую точку, а рассчитывать сразу следующую за ней (а можно установить и больший шаг).